# How to inset a new row at given position in pandas DataFrame and shift indices below +1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame

```
In [103]: df=pd.DataFrame({'A': [3,4,7,5], 'B': [6,1,3,6]})

In [104]: df
Out[104]: 
   A  B
0  3  6
1  4  1
2  7  3
3  5  6
[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

How to insert a new row with A=9 and B=9 at position with index=2 and shift indices below +1? The result is

```
In [114]: df
Out[114]: 
   A  B
0  3  6
1  4  1
2  9  9
3  7  3
4  5  6
[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be more efficient ways, but here is one approach - taking slices of the head / tail around the point you want to insert values, and stacking it all together with pd.concat.

```
In[1] pd.concat([df.loc[0:1],  pd.DataFrame({'A':9, 'B':9}, index=[0]), df.loc[2:]], ignore_index=True)

Out[92]: 
   A  B
0  3  6
1  4  1
2  9  9
3  7  3
4  5  6
```

Comment: Thanks @chrisb ! And why did you use index=[0]?

Comment: pd.concat([df.loc[0:1],  pd.DataFrame({'A':[9], 'B':[9]}), df.loc[2:]], ignore_index=True)

Comment: The temporary DataFrame that's being built just needs some index, so 0 is arbitrary (index will get rebuilt because of ignore_index on pd.concat).  Can alternatively be written as you did above.

Answer (score 1):

I thought this way was pretty interesting:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': [3,4,7,5], 'B': [6,1,3,6]})
x = len(df.index)
for item in df.index:
    if x > 2:
        df.ix[x] = df.ix[x-1]
    x = x-1
df.ix[2] = 9
```